# Solving pre logarithmic problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

How can I solve $2^{6x}$ when $8^x=3$?

Comment: You are computing $2^{6x}$?  Hint:  $2^{6x}=(2^{3x})^2$.

Comment: Thank you sir, but after that, do i have to raise 3 to 2?

Comment: $2^{6x}=\left(2^{3x}\right)^2=\left(8^x\right)^2=3^2=9$

Comment: Sir can you explain it further? :D

Comment: What part aren't you following?  $2^{3x}=(2^3)^x=8^x=3$.  Does that help?

Comment: Yes. But is the final answer 2^6x=8^2x=9? Am i right?

Answer (score 2):

$2^{6x}=2^{3\cdot 2\cdot x}=2^{3\cdot x\cdot 2}=((2^3)^x)^2=(8^x)^2=3^2=9$